# Getting an else statement and adding it to an AJAX calls function(response)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code that works great except for one small thing. If an invalid email is entered the else statement of the php comes into the response and with my current styling class for the response, it looks like it was approved.

So, I was wondering if there is anywhere I can create an else statement with my current code and pull the else response from php. If so, how could I do it?

```
 <div id="contactMessageStatus"></div>
    <div class="contactForm">
        <form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform" >
            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
            <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Send Message" id="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

AJAX

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){

    $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
    $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
    $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
     }, 2000);
    $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
    $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

PHP file to show the echoed responces:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'contact@example.com';
$subject = 'SFL Contact Form Submitted';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name. ' ' . ' Email: '.$email. ' ' . 'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: contact@example.com' . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //This method sends the mail.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}else{
echo "Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.";
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to check the response in the `function(response)` of your $.post

Comment: How can I check it? I'm just starting to learn JS, so not the best yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on comments in question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){

        $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
            if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                 }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
            }
            else {
                // whatever error handling you want goes here
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know it would be this simple. Thanks for the help!